# Why does the Java process memory still increase after calling memory.close?

Tags: java, jna, java-memory-leaks

After running the following program, the memory occupied by the Java process increased from 83M to 99M. Through monitoring, it was found that the increase was almost 1.4M several times (approximately equal to the size of the bytes array). `Memory.close()` seems to not work occasionally?
In theory, shouldn't the memory size occupied by the Java process be equal to the memory used by the program itself plus the allocated 2M memory?

```java
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File imageFile = new File("test.jpeg");
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
        byte[] bytes = bufferedImageToByteArray(image);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Pointer data = new Memory(2 * 1024 * 1024);
            data.write(0, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            if(data instanceof Memory){
                ((Memory)data).close();
            }
        }
    }

private static byte[] bufferedImageToByteArray(BufferedImage image) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[width * height * 3];
        Raster raster = image.getRaster();
        int numBands = raster.getNumBands();
        int index = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                int[] pixel = new int[numBands];
                raster.getPixel(x, y, pixel);
                // Blue
                byteArray[index++] = (byte) (pixel[2] & 0xFF);
                // Green
                byteArray[index++] = (byte) (pixel[1] & 0xFF);
                // Red
                byteArray[index++] = (byte) (pixel[0] & 0xFF);
            }
        }
        return byteArray;
    }
```

env: jdk 11, jna 5.13

[image: This is the memory utilization curve in a real scenario]

- This is the memory utilization curve in a real scenario，

Comment: Don't know if this is the case here, but memory allocators may choose to keep a freed block in the process for reuse.

Comment: What do you mean by "the memory used by the program itself"? And why do you read in the whole JPEG file, but then copy the first 2 MiB over and over to the `Memory`? And your example uses a `Pointer` local variable with a cast that wouldn't be necessary if you stick to `Memory` inside the `for` loop.

Comment: The code above is a simplified version of the problem I'm having

Comment: hi julaine, How should I verify whether this is the case you mentioned? Is there a way to manually return the memory reserved by the process to the operating system?

Comment: @rocco that is hard to verify and much harder to prevent. But this is not usually a problem. What exactly is the problem that got you profiling the java-memory usage in the first place?

Comment: @julaine I have a business scenario like this. Every time the business code is executed, the memory will increase a little. After the business code is executed, the memory is not recycled. I want to verify whether the memory is not released after memory.close or there is a problem elsewhere.

Comment: Did you try to create a dump of process to check alive objects?

Comment: After dumping the Java heap memory, the Java heap memory is normal and the memory occupied is in line with expectations. However, the memory occupied by the Java process has been increasing. Obviously, the increased memory does not belong to the heap memory.

Comment: @rocco Can you recreate the graph with just the code you have? Because I don't think that code has a leak. (even though your usage of casting to pointer and back to memory is weird and useless, you can just have `data` be of type `Memory` and the code is simpler)

Comment: Problem is, there are many ways to leak memory, so you must verify that this code snippet is what is actually causing it.